# fill a dropdown with data from a list using client object model

Tags: workflow, client-object-model, database, dropdown

how can i fill a sharepoint 2010 dropdown with data from a list using client object model?

i am trying to create an aspx workflow association form and want the initiator to choose an option from an existing list.

i am also creating this workflow in visual studio 2010.

thanks

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 2):

Why use the client object model? If you are writing a custom Aspx use the server object model.

Comment: Agreed with Chris. If you're already creating a workflow in VS2010 then you have complete access to the server object model and don't need to do anything on the client side. The controls are all built server side so just read whatever data source you want (a SharePoint I would assume) and build the controls on the form in Visual Studio. Square pegs don't fit into round holes.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly use the [CascadingDropDown](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) from the Ajax toolkit or follow this [post from MVP Mark Anderson](http://sympmarc.com/2009/07/14/cascading-columns-in-a-sharepoint-form/).